# Get reflection Constructor inside the Constructor itself

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

Let's say I have a class of `Book`s which can be instantiate using a constructor like this:

```
class Book {
    public Book(String name) {
        Constructor<Book> cons = null;
        try {
            cons = Book.class.getConstructor(String.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        //Additional detail. I will pass the 'cons' to Hibernate's constructor validation
    }
}
```

Inside the constructor `Book(String name)`, I have a need to get the reference to the constructor itself. But the problem is I have to wrap the statement with a pointless try-catch block as I know the constructor definitely exists and it sure is accessible. So **I would like to know if Java provides a way to get the reference to the constructor inside itself without having to check for those Exceptions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you can't get rid of the try-catch.

The "class.getConstructor" is not sure about the availability of the constructor you are querying, so it doesnt matter whether you are sure about the availability or not.

However,you may try google reflections instead. [Here](http://reflections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/reflections/javadoc/apidocs/index.html?org/reflections/Reflections.html) is the javadoc

I didnot use it before, but I do see a method for getting all constructors. and there is no "throws"

```
public static Set<Constructor> getAllConstructors(Class<?> type,
                                  com.google.common.base.Predicate<? super Constructor>... predicates)
get all constructors of given type, up the super class hierarchy, optionally filtered by predicates
```